# Minecraft Forge crash in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

I am new to modding in Forge and I came across an error which I can't solve.
I've correctly configured the Run/Debug configs the .toml file is fine and I left the example mod as it was.
I get this error in the crash report:

```
    ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// You should try our sister game, Minceraft!

Time: 4/6/20 2:06 AM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.rewind()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.loadIcon(MainWindow.java:188) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.36_mapped_snapshot_20200225-1.15.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.setWindowIcon(MainWindow.java:152) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.36_mapped_snapshot_20200225-1.15.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:385) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.36_mapped_snapshot_20200225-1.15.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:141) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.36_mapped_snapshot_20200225-1.15.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.java:55) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.36_mapped_snapshot_20200225-1.15.1-recomp.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:81) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:102) [forge-1.15.2-31.1.36_mapped_snapshot_20200225-1.15.1-recomp.jar:?] {}


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.loadIcon(MainWindow.java:188)
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.setWindowIcon(MainWindow.java:152)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:385)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.java:55)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:81)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65)
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:102)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.15.2
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.15.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_241, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 1863636320 bytes (1777 MB) / 3145728000 bytes (3000 MB) up to 7621050368 bytes (7268 MB)
    CPUs: 12
    JVM Flags: 1 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump
    Launched Version: MOD_DEV
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.2 build 10
    Backend API: GeForce RTX 2080/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.6.0 NVIDIA 445.75, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    CPU: <unknown>
[m[32m[02:06:26] [Render thread/INFO] [STDOUT/]: [net.minecraft.util.registry.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:110]: #@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# C:\Users\Julian Burger\Desktop\1.15.2 Mod\VoidDimension\run\.\crash-reports\crash-2020-04-06_02.06.26-client.txt
[m
```

Maybe I am missing some files I don't know.
I followed some tutorials on YouTube but I could get it to work.
I hope someone can help me because I can't help my self

Comment: I've looked over it several times, no clue.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 that you use, `java.nio.ByteBuffer.rewind()` does not exist, hence this error (it is not a public method that is therefore accessed via reflection; non-public methods are not API and should not be used at all).

A **certain Java version is required**, probably Java 11 or higher, to avoid this issue.

A Java JDK can be downloaded e.g. from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) and have to be configured in *Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs* to be able to be used in Eclipse.